# Yakuake: how to toggle (maximize) current terminal if I have split panes?

Tags: terminal, kde

In Terminator, I can easily maximize the current terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> if I have split panes.

In Yakuake, however, the only way I can do is the drag the border up or down to adjust the current terminal height.
Does Yakuake has a support for this function?

**Note**
In Terminator, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> means ([source](https://linux.die.net/man/1/terminator)):

> Toggle between showing all terminals and only showing a scaled version of the current one (zoom).

Comment: Did you try to look for it

Comment: I've been googled around for days but still with no success

Comment: I know how to maximize the whole terminal, but actually I'm asking how to maximize the current terminal if I have split panes. Sorry for the ambiguous question, please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

`yakuake` based on `konsole`. From version 2.8 default shortcut for full screen mode in `konsole` is <kbd>F11</kbd>

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=303424

Comment: I guess my question is not clear, please see the edit